# changing the height of a parent layout changes the height of a view inside it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-recyclerview

I have 2 LinearLayouts inside a FrameLayout as an Item for a recyclerView.

I want the FrameLayout to have the size of the LinearLayout that is above and when I click the FrameLayout I set the translationY of the LinearLayout that is below so you can't see it and then I animate it in.
to achieve this I set the height of the FrameLayout to the height of the layout that is above like this:

```
        holder.llAbove.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            holder.flContent.getLayoutParams().height = holder.llAbove.getHeight();
            holder.flContent.requestLayout();
        }
    });
```

and when I press it  I set the translationY of the layout that is below and animate it in.
this works great when the size of the layout that is below is fixed, but when I set it's height to wrap_content the height of the below layout becomes the size of the main FrameLayout, which screws everything up.

I tried changing the entire layout params instead of just the height like this:

```
        holder.llAbove.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,holder.llAbove.getHeight());
            holder.flContent.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
```

but then I get this Exception:

```
03-29 15:36:22.919    4298-4298/com.example.itayrabin.layouttest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.itayrabin.layouttest, PID: 4298
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams
```

and when I changed the layout params to RecylcerView.LayoutParms like this:

```
        holder.llAbove.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,holder.llAbove.getHeight());
            holder.flContent.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
```

I get this null reference exception:

```
03-29 15:38:10.554    4359-4359/com.example.itayrabin.layouttest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.itayrabin.layouttest, PID: 4359
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
```

I have tried anything I can think of.

can anyone help me?